# Determining Whether a System of Linear Equations Is Inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a question about solving systems of linear equations.

**1- Is getting a false equation during the normal process of solving a system of linear equations (e.g. substitution/elimination) is the only way we ensure this system has no solutions?**

**2- If no, what other ways available?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you count gaussian (aka row) elimination as a possibility?  Then there's no solution iff you get a row of zeros except a nonzero at the far right in the augmented matrix that you're doing row elimination on.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Actually, I didn't know anything about gaussian elimination. I've just read about it and it's an easy and great way to determine whether a system of equation has no solutions. Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If we have two equations $A=B$ and $A=C$ where $B\ne C$, then we also know the system is inconsistent, for example.

Comment: Thit is just one of what I meant by "false equation" but in more detail. Thanks anyway!